# Java Cannot read field "scale" because "multiplicand" is null

Tags: java, compiler-errors, null-pointer

Getting error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "scale" because "multiplicand" is null`. How to avoid this error?

```
BigDecimal price =  tariffs.stream() //
        .map(tariff -> tariff.getPrice()) //
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

BigDecimal productPrice = price.multiply(q).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Answer (score 1):

`q` is `null`. Simple as that. Make q be not null and this error goes away. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for more information. For example, by initializing it to `BigDecimal.ONE`, perhaps.

NB: Note that it's generally a lot easier and just all around better to use ints and longs for currency and not BigDecimal. Store the atomary unit of the currency in there: $12.34 becomes `1234`. Every currency has this concept, even bitcoin (satoshis). You can't ask a bank to transfer half a cent, so the fact that you can store half a cent in a BigDecimal isn't actually all that useful. BigDecimal isn't a 'but it can handle all cases' thing either; after all, given 4 cents, you can't distribute that evenly amongst 3 people without errors, either. Even with BigDecimal.

Comment: not agree. Example: you have calculation that results in 0.5 cents. Than you have 1M these calculations. so you lose 500k.

Comment: @Andrew you've oversimplified and that makes it so bad. What if you have a calculation that results not in 0.5, but in 0.3333 repeating? BigDecimal can't handle that either!

Comment: The _right_ solution almost always is to use longs/cents. Imagine this situation: You have the functionality "Empty bank account by dividing it equally amongst its owners". The account has 4 cents right now, and has 3 owners. Instead of using BDs and failing to do the job (because BD cannot accurately represent a third of a cent), instead, the functionality _itself_ needs to encode how to deal with this situation. An obvious and fair way to do it, is to add to the protocol: Any remaining cents are divided randomly. So, everybody gets 1 cent, use randomness to hand out the final cent.

Comment: The key isn't "use long instead of BD" so much as: "You __MUST__ think about how to deal with fractional cents, and you cannot delay the act of thinking about what should happen to them by just using BD". For example, you can't fix this by saying: Eh, well, we'll just go with 10 digits after the comma, surely that is fine. Every functionality you expose that could result in fractional cents, needs to explain _then and there_ what happens to them. Not some sort of handwavey 'we will just bookkeep the fractionals to infinite depth'.